# How to export a Blender Model to show color in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, export, blender

I have looked everywhere for an answer to this question and can't find anything that works, what am I doing wrong?!

This is what my model looks like rendered in Blender using "cycle render"
[image: Here is what my model looks like rendered in blender.]

Here is what it looks like in my THREE.js Project, it should have color. (Yes I have lights in this scene! Two in fact!)
[image]

My Blender Export Settings
[image]

The House's JSON file data
[image]

[image]

Lastly my JS. code...
[image]

So where am I going wrong here??? It's possible to export colored models right?!

Comment: I'm not an expert in `three.js` or in exporting models, but it looks like you're only using a mesh, but don't assign it to a texture. There's no such thing as a 'colored' model, models consists of meshes and their corresponding textures.

Comment: In your JSON, I only see `vertexColors: false`. try to put `vertexColors: 2` for vertex colors or `vertexColors: 1` for face colors. The exporter might be broken I don't know...

Comment: You should bake the texture first. [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, but I can't get any of your solutions to work. I think I'll just put some textures on it and call it good.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if you experience above go to "Material Properties" and try to use another material and pick your desired color. Worked for me.